# Microsoft iOS Connect Setup Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, sdk, office365

I'm trying to setup and install the ios connect sdk by [following this tutorial](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-iOS-Connect). I'm using objective-c and my minimum deployment target is ios 9.0 . Ran pod install with the necessary pods and everything, but still getting several compilation errors including "Could not build module `ADALiOS`' and a bunch of errors in the `ADPersistenTokenCache.h`. I copied the source code from an [existing sample project](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-iOS-Connect/tree/master/objective-c), so no exactly sure why the sample project works and my project doesn't. The only immediate difference that I know is that the minimum deployment target on the sample project is 8.0 while mine is 9.0 . Has anyone been able to install the ios connect sdk on versions of ios 9.0 and above, or have any idea what is going wrong?

Added image for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[NOTE regarding iOS 9](https://cocoapods.org/?q=ADALiOS)

Apple has released iOS 9 which includes support for App Transport Security (ATS). ATS restricts apps from accessing the internet unless they meet several security requirements including TLS 1.2 and SHA-256.

While Microsoft's APIs support these standards some third party APIs and content delivery networks we use have yet to be upgraded. **This means that any app that relies on Azure Active Directory or Microsoft Accounts will fail when compiled with iOS 9**.

For now our **recommendation is to disable ATS, which reverts to iOS 8 functionality**

Comment: Just for clarification, you said "fail when compile" - my projects don't even compile so i'm not sure this is the correct solution. @Steven